# Qt Webkit - Browser Interaction issue

Tags: qt, jquery, post, qtwebkit

I'm developing a Qt program that contains an OpenStreetMap application as a HTML page and this page is able to access a database -via submitting an ajax form that contains the start and end dates of queries- in order to retrieve and visualize queries on the map. I would like to move this querying process to Qt from the HTML/Javascript part. So far I managed to interact with the browser via Qt but I still have a problem that is below:

1) The fetch queries button of Qt is clicked and an alert box is supposed to pop up saying that Ajax POST is failed -the database is not on my current laptop and I should be getting the error when I click either the HTML Browser window's fetch queries button or the Qt's fetch button-

2) But also, whenever I click the Fetch queries button of the HTML Browser, it displays the POST warning but also displays extra POST warning alert boxes depending on how many times I have clicked the Qt's Fetch queries button. -for example if I have clicked the Qt's fetch queries button 5 times in a row and then clicked the HTML window's fetch button once, I get 6 POST failed messages in a row-

The HTML code is like the following:

```
<form id="ajaxForm" action="index.php" method="post">
Start <input type="text" name = "date1" id = "datepicker" value = "2011-07-13" style = "width:70px">
<input type="text" name = "time1" id = "timepicker1" value = "00:00" style = "width:40px"> 

End <input type="text" name = "date2" id = "datepicker2" value = "2011-07-13" style = "width:70px">
<input type="text" name = "time2" id = "timepicker2" value = "00:01" style = "width:40px">
```

The post method of AJAX form is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

 // ajaxForm submit
 $('#ajaxForm').submit(function() {
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'heatQuery.php',
   data: $(this).serialize(),
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(response)
   {   
       // update the points for heatmap layer          
       updateHeatMap(response);

   },
   error: function(errorMsg)
   {
       alert('Error in Ajax POST');
       }
  });

  return false;
 });
});

</script>
```

And finally, the Qt code that calls the function is this:

```
void MainWindow::onButtonClicked() // clicking the button in order to POST 
{
    //the QString a is the same ajax post function as declared above

    QString a = "$(document).ready(function(){$('#ajaxForm').submit(function() {$.ajax({type: 'POST',url: 'heatQuery.php',data: $(this).serialize(),dataType: 'json',success: function(response){updateHeatMap(response);},error: function(errorMsg){alert('Error in Ajax POST');}});return false;});});"; 

    this->view->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript(a);

}
```

Any ideas on what is wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Your HTML file you're loading in QWebview is at local path? I mean what is the URL of your HTML file?

Comment: @Ammar yes, it is like the following: C:/project/project/index.html -I have tried two seperate paths with and without spaces in their names, still got the same outcome-

Comment: And in your javascript code, you've given 'url:heatQuery.php', which means QWebview expects it to be in a local path where your HTML file is. Is it present there? It should be something like "localhost:/path/to/heatQuery.php", if you're running local server. Otherwise "www.website.com/path/to/heatQuery.php".

Comment: @Ammar well, the heatQuery.php is also in the same folder as the HTML file. I'm not running a server at the moment, so the url to the path trying the straight C:/path/to/file/heatQuery.php but the issue still persists. I don't have the start and end dates posted from Qt but calling the fetch button without queries in the HTML part shows the POST message without problems and I don't think that is also the cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have got the problem. `XMLHttpRequest` loads your local file successfully, but it returns `0` in `request.status`, thats why `error()` gets fired from your jQuery code.

I ran following example code in `QWebView`..

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();  
request.open('POST', 'file:///C:/hello.txt', true);

request.onreadystatechange = function(e) {  

    if(request.readyState == 4)
    {
        // 'responseText' will not be empty if file present..
        alert("response text: " + request.responseText);
        alert("status: " + request.status);
    }
}

request.send();
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: I thought of a possible interaction problem like that last night, apparently that is the actual cause, like you said. Just ran this one too, simply assigning it to a string and calling the evaluateJavaScript but got no alert boxes despite trying several combinations for the file names. There is a right curly bracket missing from your code for the function(e) but that also wasn't the cause.

Comment: @bremmS: Make sure you're not getting "Syntax Error" in application output window. I guess it will if you've copied above code (removing newlines) and passed it to `evaluationJavaScript()`. I don't know why it cannot parse that string. But I suggest you define a function say `test()` in HTML `<script>` tag and put above code in it. And finally call `mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript("test();")`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip, I got your example to work and it indeed returns 0 in request.status. What should I be doing next in order to actually reach the file via Qt? Keep trying file paths until I get something other than 0 in the example you provided or is there something else?

Comment: providing paths of some random .txt files also yield 0 for some reason -I tried C: and D: drives, also added and removed the file:// as prefix of path-

Comment: @bremmS: Ya `request.status` will be indeed `0` and it seems we cannot do anything about it (unless you switch on to use a server, rather than loading local files), but the point is that your file will get loaded successfully too. I hope you're getting file's content in `request.responseText` via alert!!!!